# "Charge it by the blink" vs. "charge it in blinks"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

Which of these sentences is grammatically and semantically more appropriate?

> - Lawyers measure time and charge it by the blink.
> - Lawyers measure time and charge it in blinks.

Comment: I would expect _charge it in_ to be followed by a monetary denomination, e.g. _charge it in dollars_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Lawyers measure time and charge it by the blink" retains the structure of the phrase "charge by the hour" on which the wordplay depends (one doesn't tend to "charge in hours"), so is probably the better choice.